# ORM querying with transitive dependency

Tags: hibernate, database-design, orm, coldfusion, hql

Here's is a part of my database schema:
[image]

So I'm using the tables pages,points and items to generate the layout of my page. To each item is also tied an itemData. All my tables models are created and their relationship defined. I can generate a page by looping through the result of the following query:

```
<cfset variables.page = EntityLoad("Page", {id=arguments.id}, true)>
```

Now the problem comes when I try to do the same thing, but **load only the itemsData from a single "idee"** which is an idea in french. I can't think of a way to do this with entityLoad so I tried using HQL:

```
<cfset variables.page = ORMExecuteQuery("
    select  p
        from Page p
        left join p.points po
        left join po.items it           
        left join it.itemsData id
        where p.id = :pid and id.idIdee = :iid", {pid=arguments.id, iid=session.user.idee}, true)>
```

which seems close to it but that's not it ... I sometimes get more than 1 row etc etc.

Any ORM guru knows how I could handle this?

Answer (score 1):

When querying with NH you get always complete objects. It means, that you can't filter the ideas of an itemsData with a query (you just can find itemsData by idea, but these itemsData will always be complete, with all the ideas attached to it).

In NH, you could use filter for this.

It would be much easier to support a link from the idee to the itemsData. Then you just load the Idee (you have its id) and then you have the ItemsData attached to it.

```
class Idee
{
  IList<ItemsData> ItemsData { get; private set; }
}
```

You just need to map it as inverse bag.

Comment: Ok got it, instead of loading my page first I had to load an Idee, then I can go up to my pages. Thank you.

Comment: In fact it doesn't entirely solve my problem, since it is possible that there are just no itemsData defined (yet) for an Idee, which would make it impossible to go up to the pages.

Comment: @Ownatik: you still can load the page if you don't find it otherwise.

Comment: The problem was that I had defined a one-to-one instead of a many-to-one relationship between items and itemsData.